# Matplotlib: How do I add a 1 inch gap to the left side of my plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm generating 3 plots on an A4 page using python and Matplotlib. They are being saved as a PDF file. They will eventually be printed and added to a ring binder. However, the plots are flush with the left hand side. I need to add a gap of about 1 inch for the punch holes.

How do I add the gap to the left hand side?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest has a solution for you that seems to work. That being said, I don't think its a good idea to rely on Matplotlib to deal with page layouting. For that I would choose a different tool. That way Matplotlib can worry about the perfect layouting in the local figure space while some other layouting tool eg. LaTeX can worry about page layouting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add some margin on the left via `subplots_adjust`. E.g. to have the left side of the axes start at 20% of the figure width, use

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
```

Since we do not know anything about the kind of plot you have and the possible printer margins etc, you need to calculate the number to use here for a one inch spacing on the printed figure yourself.